# VBA macro SQL syntax error operator missing

Tags: sql, excel, vba

SQL Query isn't working Error Message

> VBA Macro Sql Syntax Error Operator missing in query expression
> 'Count(Distinct Customerid)>1'

```
strSQL = "SELECT Job_Type_Name FROM [Master Data$A:P] GROUP BY
customerid HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT customerid) > " & 1
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Even if you fix the syntax, this will **never** return any rows. If you count distinct on the exact field used for the group by then each group will **always** be exactly 1.